# Need help with a regex pattern for matching part of word until next uppercase letter

Tags: c#, regex, matching

I need part of a word. For example if we have `"CheckResults"` I just want to get `"Check"`. Can someone help me with regex for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Finds the begining of a word and then matches until the end of the word or a capital letter.  If the word won't always be capitalized, use this:

```
\b[A-Z]?[a-z]+
```